# How can AS/400 macro call Windows batch with returned value

Tags: batch-file, macros, ibm-midrange

I run a macro which calls a batch file. I retrieve some data in the batch file from user input. I want to return to the macro with the values entered and use them in my macro. How can this be accomplished? 
This is the macro I want to run

```
[PCOMM SCRIPT HEADER]
LANGUAGE=VBSCRIPT
DESCRIPTION=Remote Command Demo
[PCOMM SCRIPT SOURCE]
Dim wsh
Set wsh=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wsh.Run("c:\ahc\fileup.bat")

"ahc
[tab field]
"ahc
[enter]
[enter]
"RSTLIB SAVLIB(update) DEV(*SAVF) SAVF(AHCPGM/update)
[enter]
"RSTLIB SAVLIB(update) DEV(*SAVF) SAVF(AHCPGM/update) MBROPT(*ALL) ALWOBJDIF(*ALL) RSTLIB(AHCPGM)
[enter]
```

This is the batch file

```
@echo off

SET /P name= Please enter in user name:
SET /P userpw= Please enter in user password:
SET /P IPaddr= Please enter in IP address of the AS400:
SET /P update= Which update is this? (ie PCDISxxxxx):   *This is the value I want to return*

echo user>> ftpcmd.dat
echo %name%>> ftpcmd.dat
echo %userpw%>> ftpcmd.dat
echo bin>> ftpcmd.dat
echo lcd c:\ahc>> ftpcmd.dat
echo cd /qsys.lib/ahcpgm.lib>> ftpcmd.dat
echo put %1 %update%.savf>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat %IPaddr%
del ftpcmd.dat
```

Comment: What kind of macro is that? What application is running that macro?

Comment: This is an IBM macro to restore a save files into a library. The batch file FTP the save file into the iSeries. The macro restores the save file into a library.

Comment: This appears to be a macro executed by IBM i Access or one of its predecessors. Probably the later since the macro editing facility no longer exists in the last release off IBM i Access, and likely is totally nonexistant in ACS (the current client for IBM i). Maybe try something like Ublu, you will probab ly have more luck, and since it is currently being developed, you are more likely to get support.

Comment: Better would probably be not to use the built in macro language and use VB macros instead. I don't know that any feature exists for the macro language to retrieve data from a Windows batch process.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy I use IBM i Access Client Solutions and macros with macro editor work fine. However, the macro _language_ has changed and now looks more like a markup language more like XML.